# Is there a kind of "exponential upvoting effect" for high rep users?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have noticed my reputation points growing started to boost at some point when I had already received a few +1k rep, at least when it was +10k.

On the one hand, you're going to learn how to give better answers over the time, on the other hand I sometimes even receive unsolicited upvotes (where I decided to delete a wrong or inappropriate answer of mine).

Does anyone else notice this effect? What are sound reasons explaining that?
<sub>I'm well aware, there might be no **final answer** for these questions, though I'm curious and want to receive your observation and discuss what's going on.</sub>

---

What made me ask, was this little comment discussion from today:

> [image]

In fact I was wondering how that guy could receive so many reputation points in that relatively short time period. It fits for the calculational reasonings (3 month => 90 days * max 200 a day => 18000). But well, that's remarkable though.

---

As a side note: I was wondering about these +200 rep per day peaks:

[image]

Is it possible, these came in from accepted bounty rewards? I'd suspect reputation points gained through bounty accepts, may override the 200+ reputation point limit per day.

---

Another [very notable question](https://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster) / [user](https://superuser.com/users/349115/ydaetskcor) regarding my concerns.

Comment: The more answers you have on the network the more people are going to run into your answers when they search for stuff and the more you are going to get rep for old answers.

Comment: @Louis Yeah, that's another source for gaining rep of course. But what I'm asking about, is that high rep user's answers (or even questions) are to some point preferred blindly.

Comment: Well, some people clearly do not put much care in voting. I would not be surprised if they are easily swayed by reputation irrespective of the merits of a post. I don't know whether the effect is exponential.

Comment: you may have knowingly or not, learned to "sculpt" answers so they are more likely to get upvotes; and avoid bothering to answer crap question unlikely to be viewed by others and/or posted by those likely to be hit-and-run posters

Comment: Question: Is the 200 max for all of your answers combined? Or any one answer?

Comment: @JayBlanchard AFAIK The rep limit is +200 a day, independent of the actions you gain it from (not so sure about achieving bounty points, I'd guess that's over these limiting rules).

Comment: Cool, I was just curious how the system worked @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: LOOK!  I'M FAMOUS!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The 15 points you get for an accepted answer is not affected by the daily rep limit. So you can get over 200 rep points in day without receiving points from an accepted bounty.

Comment: @dano THX for that info, I didn't know that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ his comment is in your screenshot...

Comment: The answer is 42.

Comment: @Zack I doubt that I found the very final question about life and everything here. But may be, who knows? We have to ask the computers. I tried to improve my question a little more though ...

Comment: No need for a DE query. It's here: http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation

Comment: @Mysticial [Got it!](http://stackexchange.com/users/1511352/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96?tab=reputation)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ wow i only seen this on the hot topics on the right side. anyways, my participation varies from day to day, sometimes i participate like 16+ hours a day, and sometimes not at all like today because my tooth hurts like hell and i need to see a dentist. anyways i just got lucky cuz there is one point almost all my answers that day got accepted and that doesn't effect the cap just as dano has said.

Comment: Back when I had under 15k rep I had a couple of instances where a higher-rep user would post an answer on a question which I answered a while beforehand, to then find OP commenting on my answer with "I like your answer but *x* has higher rep so I'll accept that answer instead." Even when our answers are identical in both content and quality. People assume that users with higher reputation know more and that their answers are better - although this does often go hand in hand anyway. People also do vote based on how much reputation a user has, and I've seen a few comments like "Wow 50k rep? +1".

Comment: I never look at a person's rep when upvoting, and I presume most act similarly.  Questions and answers should only be judged on their own merit.

Comment: It's certainly true that high-rep users get upvotes just because of who they are, especially if they're well-known within the tags they frequent.  People decide that an answer must be correct because it's posted by a high-rep user, and vote accordingly.  On this site, Jon Skeet could fart and get 20 upvotes for it.  But this isn't a bad thing.  The reason why the site displays the reputation of each respondent is to give people some clue about whom to trust.

Comment: I downvoted to counterbalance the effect you are highlighting :D

Comment: @anderstood At the moment I didn't got some additional upvotes because of just asking on MSO. It's different, if my question was upvoted here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and I didn't downvote, I was just joking. More seriously: rep is a measure, and like any "scalar" measure of something complex, it only gives one side of it. Also, very basic questions often receive a huge number of upvotes because many users are concerned (e.g. "how to delete a git repository").

Comment: @Ghost /No Sarcasm, real story/ Strange enough, I've also got serious toothaches today (You're sure no voodoo applies?!?), but I'm actually getting better (bought a water-pik and thoroughly rinsed).

Comment: @DarrenRinger _"and I presume most act similarly"_ You show very righteous and should be kept on behavior, but I doubt that applies for the masses ...

Comment: @Ghost And _"Get well soon!"_ of course. Heads up, that was no way meant to blame you anyhow.

Comment: Why can't we just hide users rep in the main page (or maybe badges as well), and only show it in the users' profile page?  From what I can see there are two problems: 1. high rep users' answer/question tends to draw more up-votes (yes, I mean blind votes); 2. high rep users' questions and answers tends to be more protected by other users when it comes to close/down-votes.

Comment: I have a friend who has told me that if he sees two identical answers he upvotes/accepts the one from the user with higher rep. To me this makes no sense, I do the opposite; if I see, for example, two users (one low rep one high) answering a simple google-able/obvious but not off-topic question, I will upvote the low rep user's answer but not the high. It bugs me how many users I see with 100K rep who *only* answer "how do I parse this DateTime" and "how do I parameterize my SQL queries" (I hang out on the C# tag). If it's a more involved question I'll upvote both good answers.

Comment: @eddie_cat I once had a phase, when my considerations where the same as yours, and I preferred upvoting the lower rep users. Though I've learned, that the answerers rep shouldn't be taken into consideration for up-/downvoting an answer at all. Judge by the contents of the answer, if they're really identical and you think they deserve upvoting, upvote both.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are several effects that kick in, some you have control over, others you don't.

#### Writing skill matters

As you ask and answer more questions, typically your skill at writing good questions and answers will improve.  Better written posts will get more up votes.  This is especially the case with older posts as people find them and up vote them because they are well written.

One will typically also learn how to tailor the post to the audience and be able to engage them through the entire post (which gets more up votes if they read to the end rather than skipping to the next one).

The ability to properly tailor the post to the audience (writing level for beginner or expert - walking through the code or just giving a block) then increases the chances that the answer will be accepted (more on this in a bit).  This makes the post the top one seen on the page and also has other nice reputation points boosting side effects (going above the reputation points cap for a day).

#### More likely to find the post

It is a bit harder on Stack Overflow than other sites, but can still be appreciable when dealing within certain tags.  As you write more, your posts will be found more. Getting votes is in part a point of getting views on posts.  If you have a few answers on obscure questions you won't get as many as you would if you have more answers on more trafficked questions.

#### Prefer to answer better questions

[FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) is what it is, but those questions typically disappear into obscurity. The good questions that people answer will get more votes over time than some FGITW answer on a poorly written question. This again goes to the 'more likely to find the post' aspect mentioned previously.

There is also an allure for low reputation points users to post answers in these questions (hoping to catch some of the coattails?).  Noting one of my answers on another site, it typically gets a new answer in the post about every other week or so.  Having the top voted answer in it, each time that happens I get more reputation points.

#### Top answers get more votes

If you do have a top answer, it is likely to get more up votes.  That's again part of the draw of FGITW.  But once you get past that, a well written post at the top may often get another up vote and the second post is less likely to do so.  This also plays into the 'writing skill matters' as a well written post is more likely to become a top answer.

#### People recognize the avatar

Having a non user1234 name with a non-pragmatic avatar will draw eyeballs.  Some will recognize you and upvote just because.  As you get more recognized within a given community, this will become more prevalent.

#### Seen as the authority

There are times when if you want to find an answer you may go to that person's profile and search for the keywords and tags you are looking for - noting that they will likely have the *best* answer out there.  For example, someone may do a search such as [user:22656 null pointer [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a22656%20null%20pointer%20%5bjava%5d) (note: user 22656 is Jon Skeet) *looking* for an answer that he gave on null pointers or trying to glean some of the insight he has into the related design issues of null pointers.

#### Engagement in the site

High reputation points users tend to be more engaged in the site and may go back to review their old posts and fix them.  This fixing of old posts will bump it and again, attract eyeballs and votes.

#### Off site funnels

While it's a lottery, sometimes a well written question and answer will find its way to [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit), [Ars Technica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Technica), or [Hacker News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News). Posts in these sites can have long tails of upvotes that continue to provide returns months later from someone finding the post over there.  The key is to have something that someone wants to read and follows on to go read it.  This requires more than a code dump (and goes back to that writing skill matters bit).

---

So yes, it does happen for a variety of reasons, and combined they have a positive feedback loop upon up votes and reputation.

Comment: That's a number of sound reasonings explaining such effect.

Comment: "Prefer to answer better questions." Hrrm... depends what you mean by "better". My most upvoted posts are for answers that in all honesty are rather pedestrian, *because the question was pedestrian too*. I sure would not call them "better". They are just simpler. Those answers I posted to high quality but difficult questions don't get as many views or as many votes. Maybe we can agree on "more likely to avoid atrocious questions." :)

Comment: @Louis the ones that people find later tend to be the 'better' ones for some degree of better.  The boring pedestrian ones that people have asked 1000x times before? You're competing for eyeballs (and votes) with those 1000x questions and 2000x answers.  The *good*, well written questions that people remember and come back to and reference in other posts or show up with a nice highly voted number in related questions or are the dup targets (in part because they remember them) - those are the ones I'm referring to.

Comment: @Louis Good point, but that's concerning the [quite foggy stuff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276303/should-provided-code-in-an-answer-work), doesn't it?

Comment: I would add that skill to _tailor the post_ to the asker' needs increases chances for answer to be accepted, with all the involved rep-related benefits: going over rep limit, top answer position allowing to gain more votes in the future

Comment: the way how new answer relates to top voted one getting more votes may be not evident for readers who aren't aware that new answers [meta-tag:bump] the question which brings additional eyeballs

Comment: Over quality what matters more is how many people are likely to encounter that problem & search for it(i.e. how common is that problem). A simple but *very* common problem that has a ready-made (RTFM type) answer would receive regular upvotes than most others.

Comment: @BlueMoon that depends on how findable the question itself is.  Some of those early 'simple' questions have indeed had numerous dividends on the simple and straight forward answer.  However, for a person writing for today those new questions are few and far between (that actually stick around).  If you are writing for the long term rep, higher quality answers are often better than the 'here is the code' answer.

Comment: No, no. I am not talking about 'here is the code' kinds. Such as: use flag -s to do this; use this tool that does it; use grep command; etc. a[i] vs i[a] in C, i=i++ * i++; etc that every newbie faces it. Of course, those kinds are somewhat reached a threshold as they have been asked in the early days of SO. But there's always new technology/technique/language or new problem in the existing domain that could have trivial solutions.

Comment: @BlueMoon There's a notable _"RTFM type"_ questions highly voted and leading to the right answers. Aren't these what we're considering to be a canonical?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes..And such questions are always possible to ask in every programming language as they evolve and new features/technologies come out.

Comment: i also think time is a big factor here, of course if you spend like half a day answering questions, and answering them in the best of your abilities will definitely garner points at the end of the day.

Answer (score 12):

I was a bit surprised at your use of the word "exponential", so I thought it would be interesting to chart my own reputation history. By itself, that isn't very revealing. What we really want to know is the relationship between the rate of reputation growth and the rate of answering! Here it is:

[image]

The top is a simple accumulating count of answers. The bottom is rep. Well, what do you know - *they are almost a perfect match!* So what this shows is that there is *no* exponential growth accruing whatsoever. This is *not* a machine that will go of itself. The way to increase reputation is to *keep answering*. There is no royal road to geometry after all.

It's an interesting result. One of my earliest answers is responsible, all by itself, for quite a sizable chunk of my rep. So you see, the fact that it was *early* was significant, like giving a child a small stock investment. That demonstrates how the mere lapse of time matters. But of course, on the other extreme, I have also given a huge number of answers that never gained me any rep at all - a long, useless tail... So for me, at least, it all comes out in the wash and reputation is more or less in proportion to the number of answers I've given.

Ultimately, it's *all* about the future. When you are answering, you are laying down a legacy. You have no idea what that legacy will be; it can be quite surprising what answers turn out to be useful for lots of people over time. But that - the inheritance from the accumulated years of answering questions - is where rep ultimately comes from. See also the second part of my answer here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271754/341994.

Comment: I'd point out that at a certain point, one can't do more than [linear](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) because of repcaps.  However, there is a period prior to hitting (or close to) recaps every day during which a user could experience faster than linear growth because of a number of answers and investment in the site.

Comment: Yeah, @Mystical proposed [this graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/1511352/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96?tab=reputation), and I see it isn't really exponential, but has a similar tendency.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've been thinking: it would be a better graph if it also included the rate of answering - in other words, does rep grow significantly faster than the answering rate? My guess is that it grows only a tiny bit faster if at all. I may try to modify my graph to show that.

Comment: @matt Your graph gave me a lot of confidence :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added the second half of the graph. Quite revealing, I think; I believe that, at least in this instance, the hypothesis is disproved! :)

Answer (score 11):

It's a very crude statistic, but 'points per answer' is interesting.  For the top 10 users on SO, the values (as of approximately 2014-11-08 17:40Z), the statistics are:

- Jon Skeet (725k) — 30379 answers, 23.86 points per answer (31 questions)
- Darin Dimitrov (551k) — 20636 answers, 26.69 points per answer (34 questions)
- BalusC (521k) — 15726 answers, 33.11 points per answer (14 questions)
- Marc Gravell (504k) — 13117 answers, 38.40 points per answer (43 questions)
- Hans Passant (499k) — 14408 answers, 34.66 points per answer (2 questions)
- VonC (442k) — 11394 answers, 38.79 points per answer (16 questions)
- CommonsWare (402k) — 13594 answers, 30.87 points per answer (16 questions)
- SLaks (413k) — 13660 answers, 30.23 points per answer (51 questions)
- Greg Hewgill (378k) — 5219 answers, 72.49 points per answer (46 questions)
- paxdiablo (363k) — 8007 answers, 45.31 points per answer (154 questions)

The statistic is crude because it ignores the points from questions, but given the small number of questions compared to the answers (only paxdiablo has a question/answer ratio of more than 1% in this sample), this effect is probably small.

It is quite clear that Jon Skeet writes a *lot* of answers (half as many again as Darin Dimitrov); that's how he gets a lot of points.  It's not so much that every answer of his gets a lot of up-votes (though some undoubtedly do) as that he writes a lot of answers that get some up-votes (and many of them are accepted, and the acceptance points no longer count towards the daily cap, though they did at one time early on).

Comment: I think all those users are pretty much limited by the 200/day rep cap. Some of them would probably have several million points without the cap. If you look at the monthly rep results, the top users pretty consistently get 300 points/day. That's 200 for the capped upvotes, plus a few accepted answers and a bounty here and there. But most of them must get way more than 20 upvotes per day.

Comment: @RetoKoradi note that I didn't get limited by rep cap for a 900+ days, before finally getting to 200+ a day (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204782/top-users-by-reputation-with-rep-cap-and-member-for-days). The accept rate is also important to consider:http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/184013/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers?MinAnswers=10000). Even without rep cap, I wouldn't have "millions"... only 620K+ (instead of 440): http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/24898/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed?UserId=6309

Comment: @RetoKoradi for the rep cap effect on top users: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84763/percent-lost-to-reputation-cap-among-top-1000-users. For the average score: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/85979/top-100-mass-answerers. Average rep per day: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35545/top-users-by-reputation-per-day

Comment: @VonC Very interesting queries, thanks! I would have expected that the top users would lose more to the rep cap. Except for one of them, it's not *that* much. And now I know that my accept rate is higher than Jon Skeet. :)

Answer (score 5):

Something to keep in mind is that not all of your rep will come from votes immediately after posting - future readers stumbling across a good answer may upvote it long after it was written. Because of that, the more answers you have out there over a longer time, the more you're going to gain reputation just from the increased likelihood that someone sees one of your posts. That likely explains some of the exponential nature of the gains - it's a function of your total number of posts out there over time, which will typically correlate as higher rep users are going to be those who have posted more.

Comment: See my comment's for @Louis, covering these points. I'm aware of that of course.

Comment: Well beyond that, it's sort of speculation. Nobody can say why someone else up or downvoted a post unless they commented about it, so all we could really do is guess whether people are voting up your posts because they're good or because they're treating you special.

Comment: At some point you're going to notice an _exponantially_ growing rep, since some people manage to get this experience in such of a short time, it's something beyond the reasons you mentioned. These will count, but not if you aren't actually continuing  answering more questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Exponentially increasing *rep* isn't really possible unless the masses start giving out bounties. You're capped to 200 a day by votes - which is linear. And even Jon Skeet only has 24 hours a day to get +15 accepts. Unless of course the account is run by an exponentially growing # of people - then all bets are off.

Comment: @Mysticial Very good point about the actually expectable _exponential_ rep growth, as I introduced with the question.