# Are there statistics on the percentage of users over time, that are high reputation/high answer to question ratio?

Tags: discussion, statistics

This thought occurred to me recently.

When Stack Overflow started, there must have been a lot of users who were already very experienced programmers, who then fit into SO mostly answering questions.

However, in the seven years that SO has grown, each year you have new users, who presumably would be beginner programmers ie. experienced programmers would already have joined.

These users are likely to ask more questions than give answers.

Do statistics reflect this?

Comment: It seems you're experienced with SQL. Try it yourself: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is an assumption here that all experienced programmers joined on day one, which cannot be true by a long stretch.

Comment: @pnuts: why is that unlikely? And what has that got to do with experienced programmers joining later?

Comment: @pnuts: I have nearly 20 years of programming experience. I didn't really become active on the site until summer 2012. I just didn't 'connect' with the site before then. I'm surely not an exception.

Comment: It seems to me that the great majority of "beginner questions" have already been answered (a basic model of the site) such that most of the newer questions are higher-level.

Comment: @pnuts I stand corrected.  I guffawed and felt better about my own "n00b" status ;-)

Comment: @beardedmike "...such that most of the newer questions are higher-level" Are you being sarcastic!?  I float around the [qt] tag and the average question quality over the last two or three years has plummeted (like this little gem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855685/how-can-i-use-common-variable-in-multiple-cpp-file-in-qt), and that's a relatively niche tag, I dread to think what common ones are like...

Comment: @MartijnPieters "I have nearly 20 years of programming experience. I didn't really become active on the site until summer 2012." And now he is the ruler of the Queen's Nav-ee!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we understand your question to be: **"For users who joined on a given date, what percentage of them are 'high reputation' users?"**, then [**this SEDE query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/306334/percentage-of-high-rep-users-by-join-date?HighScore=200#graph) shows that.  You can easily input whatever value (R) you consider denotes 'high reputation'.

Plotting the results for several R values yields:

[(Click for a larger image)

[image: Percentage High-rep users by join date]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvULs.jpg)

The graph seems to show several effects:

- The (surviving) [Private Beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/) users did quite well.
- As did the early public adopters (Starting at roughly "Oct 08" on the graph)
- Not sure why there is a sharp dropoff for users who joined after Aug 09.  Were these most affected by [*The Great Reputation Recalc* of March, 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)?
- Note that most lines level off for a few months starting March, 2010.
- Pruning old, low-contributing users should cause a jump in the percentages. Does this explain the spike and the different slopes before October 2011?

---

---

## Ratio of Answers to questions

[The query plotting A/Q ratio by join date](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/306353/percentage-of-users-with-a-high-answer-to-questions-ratio-by-join-date?HighAtoQRatio=3#graph) has similar shapes. Here it is for users having A/Q >= 3:

[(Click for a larger image)

[image: Percentage High A/Q users by join date]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmUu8.jpg)

I now suspect that each of the 3 distinct jumps, in both kinds of graphs, represent a culling of (low value) users.  Is there any way to confirm that?

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Fun question.

Comment: I would guess that the drop *in percentage* is caused by SO gaining momentum, and more and more users joining not all of whom were blessed. If you look at [the absolute counts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/306791/percentage-of-high-rep-users-by-join-date?HighScore=1000#graph), their numbers are quite constant in fact (declining towards the end just because those users had not had the *time* to acquire that reputation while they possess the quality).

Comment: Aug 09 was about the time they started to crack-down on all the joke and subjective questions.  Lots of users left.  Lots of experts started posting answers.

Comment: @Bergi, those numbers are constant sure, but *they're* not the hind of users who would get pruned from the system.  Pruning low-rep users would cause the jumps in the percentages, but not the absolute counts of high-rep users.

Answer (score 12):

If we [look at some data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305166#graph), we can say that there is a non-linear decrease in average rep. This is grouped by the week a user joined:

[image]

By July 2012, we're looking at <100 reputation averages per week. If we adjust this to only account for users with reputation > 200, (meaning they're actually interested in the site and didn't just post one question and move on), we get a better picture:

[image]

This second graph shows, aside from the initial users during the first weeks (which would be developers and early beta testers), there's a roughly linear trend for reputation.

I'm sure there's much more one can do with this data, go for it!

Comment: Doesn't this just show that rep must be accumulated over time? For a bit there I was assuming you were averaging the rep gain per week to determine continuous rate (which is still problematic, given the way old posts cost no further effort and continue to generate rep), but that's not what the query does.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that, if all users are of the same quality regardless of when they joined, their rep should be linearly proportional to how long they've been around. That's pretty questionable. If most rep is earned from being the fastest gun in the west on questions that fade into the shadows as soon as they are answered, then that's probably roughly true. But if people write posts linearly over time, and those posts gain rep linearly over time, then we should expect someone's rep to be proportional to the *square* of how long they've been a user.

Comment: (Of course, it's also possible that voting patterns and question exposure have changed over time in ways unrelated to post quality, which would further confound attempting to use rep-over-time as a metric for programmer-quality-over-time as the OP is trying to do.)

Comment: What @NathanTuggy said.  This only appears to demonstrate that the more time a user spends on the site, the more likely they are to have a higher rep.  Possibly it also suggests that the more users there are, the harder it is for new users to acquire rep.  More pertinent to the question asked might be a similar graph that tracks the average ratio of <answers> / <questions> posted by each group of users.  If the OP's premise is correct, there should be a trend showing newer users having lower ratios (i.e. asking more questions) than older users.

Comment: @MarkAmery "then we should expect someone's rep to be proportional to the square of how long they've been a user" Well, it isn't (unless you are Jon Skeet or someone of that ilk). See the discussion (and especially my answer) here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276309/is-there-a-kind-of-exponential-upvoting-effect-for-high-rep-users