# Answer with untested code

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, first-post-review

During a review of a First Post, I got the following answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519947/online-stores-product-availability-check-from-given-url) to review :

[image]

It is the "I don't know if this would work though" that makes me feel uncomfortable. There has been asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276303/should-provided-code-in-an-answer-work/276375#276375) on Meta Stack Overflow, but the answer was something like "Use your best judgement". My question is: what is your *best judgement*? I would feel to downvote and comment 'Please only add code of which you know it works', but on the other hand it is a possible correct answer.

Comment: My best judgment would be that I have no clue whether the answer is wrong or right, so I skip this particular review. (If in doubt I'm usually a bit of a pro contribution fan. You can still downvote the answer later, at least it looks formally okay. So I believe it was done in good faith.)

Comment: Well I can see he meant "I don't know if this would work for your case". Giving him the benefit of the doubt here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you verify that it is an incorrect answer? If so, it deserves a downvote. Otherwise, a lot of questions have been answered without explicit testing, because of any number of the following reasons:

- no access to external resources needed to reproduce the problem
- no access to an IDE / compiler (e.g. when answering via the phone)
- just enough time to write a quick answer, but not to test it

When a colleague asks me a coding question, and I have little time (or I'm somewhere else and can't verify it directly), I can just give a few hints, or correct the code snippet he sent in my e-mail client. Does my lack of testing make the answer less valuable for him?

As always, when in doubt during a review, hit the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button - [there's no shame in using Skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: Normally, I use the `skip` button when I'm unsure. But I have seen this quite often, lately, which is why I decided to ask this question on META. I will stick to the `skip` way then!

Answer (score 2):

The question is too broad and should not be answered. The OP is basically asking *"How do I scrape a website"*, without even mentioning a programming language. From their question it does not appear they've done any research or other effort.

People shouldn't answer such questions,

However, the phrase *"I would use some JS"* indicates the answerer has no clue what the OP is trying to do. In what context would this JS run?

Even if you look through that, the approach demonstrated by the answerer shows that they do not know how to robustly scrape a website. You don't use dumb string matching for that.

So no, you shouldn't downvote because it wasn't tested, you should downvote because it's an unusable naive approach that will not work, not in this case, and not in most cases.